# Workflow Task popup in Outlook 2010 opens constantly

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-enterprise

I've came across an issue regarding approval workflow. I set up Approval workflow in SharePoint and want to approve by using "Open this task" button, but when I click this button, Workflow task popup (**Retrieving task -  Workflow tasks details are being retrieved from the server**) opens constantly.

So I still can't do approval task by using Outlook 2010.

Is there anyone come across this problem?

Regards,

- T.s -

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the problems on machines after applying Service Pack 1 of Office 2010 and when the task in SharePoint has been deleted. Unfortunatley no workaround so far.

Comment: So I should be uninstalling SP1 and then re-install Office 2010 without SPack...?

Answer (score 0):

We recently had this issue on a SharePoint 2010 system upgraded from SharePoint 2007. The issue arose when someone tried to open a task that was completed from a workflow that originated in SharePoint 2007 using ASPX forms to collect the data. Opening them in SharePoint designer and republishing them to get the new InfoPath forms generated allowed all new tasks to be opened via Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. In my case the webapp is using mixed authentication (win + FBA). If I disable FBA auth. everything works perfect. Any workaround for this ?

@thuan is this your case too ?